# View-related privileges in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I grant view-related privileges to a user in MySQL (without granting all privileges)? I get this error when I try to do a `mysqldump`:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `view_household`': SHOW VIEW command denied to user 'backup'@'localhost' for table 'view_household' (1142)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`grant show view on *.* to 'backup'@'localhost'`

Comment: Probably `*.*` it's a little wide. Usually with `dbName.*` is enough.